Adding strings to a stack, getting incorrect output
Working on this problem and the code runs fine however if the user inputs strings with spaces, the stack's length is counted wrong. My expected output is 9 and I'm getting 14. My goal is to display the number of elements on the first line, the value at the top of the stack on the next line, and display the number of elements in the stack again.
Here is a snippet of my getLength function
   int getLength() {
      return length;
   }

And here is my main function, I believe I'm getting the wrong output because of my while loop but I'm not sure what the issue is.
int main() {

     Stack_str s;
     string item;
     string userInput;

     while (true) {
      // Prompt the user for input
      cin >> userInput;

      // Check if user wants to stop entering string input
      if (userInput == "0") {
         break; // Breaks from loop if user enters "0"
      }

      // Push the user input into the stack
      s.push(userInput);

     }

     // Display stack
     cout << s.getLength() << endl;

     if (!s.isEmpty()) {
      cout << s.peek() << endl;
     } else {
      cout << "Empty Stack!" << endl;
     }
     cout << s.getLength() << endl;

     return 0;

Here is my program input and output:
Input:
stack
queue
linked list
tree
binary tree
binary search tree
heap
hash table
graph
0

My Output:
14
graph
14

Expected Output:
9
graph
9

I've tried adding debugging features to count the amount of strings being pushed and I can see that it is pushing 14 instead of 9.

What does stack_str look like

Why don't you use std::stack<std::string>, the C++ standard library has a lot of (tested) building blocks for you to (re)use... so use them. Side note : also stop using using namespace std;

cin >> userInput; does not include spaces in the string it returns. If you want to read spaces then use getline(cin, userinput); to read one line at a time

Your input has 14 words, so you get 14 as the stack size. The error is that you think that if you enter some of the words on the same line they count as one word. That is not true. cin >> userInput reads one word at a time. getline(cin, userinput); reads one line at a time.

A simple cout << userInput << '\n'; after the cin >> userInput; would have shown you your mistake, where you are only getting a single word from a multi-word input.  Then the question would become focused, and you would see it has nothing to do with std::stack or data structures.  Before posting questions, make sure you are putting in at least some debugging effort, even if it's intermediate output statements.
